# pandas split data-frame into two if an element in a column is seen twice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, split

Let's say I have a `dataframe` in python like below:

```
DateTime   A, B
12/03/2020 1, 40
12/03/2020 2, 30
13/03/2020 12, 32
13/03/2020 90, 2
```

I want to split these into two `dataframes` each with unique dates like below

**df1**

```
DateTime,  A, B
12/03/2020 1, 40
13/03/2020 12, 32
```

**df2**

```
DateTime,  A, B
12/03/2020 2, 30
13/03/2020 90, 2
```

The order is important. I.e. The first date of each couple should all be in one `dataframe` and the second date in another.

How can one achieve this in `pandas`?

**NB:** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649084/how-to-split-a-dataframe-when-a-row-value-in-a-specific-column-changes), chosen as duplicate does not help me. I am trying to achieve something different.

Comment: try `{f'df{key}' : data for key, data in df.groupby(df.groupby('DateTime').cumcount())}`

Comment: I don't know why this question has been closed. The link to the answer does not help me whatsoever. People should read the question carefully before they close someone's post.

Comment: @Manakin this does help me. I don't know If you can post it as an answer now that the question has been marked as duplicate.

Comment: It's fine - I can find another duplicate this Q has been asked before :) don't worry about the dupe hammer, I think 60-70 % of questions are duplicates

Comment: I wouldn't have asked the question if SEO did a better job in recognizing it.

Comment: There's no cumcount needed though. Updated the dupe to generate a df of lists, which is more suited here @Manakin

Comment: @Manakin another issue is that this return a dict rather than two dataframes

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821090/split-dataframe-randomly-dependent-on-unique-values)?